# Requested URL /main was not found

Tags: php

Ubuntu 14

I get this error when i try to access index.php

> The requested URL /main was not found on this server.

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

and the index.php starts like this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
     header('Location: /main');
exit();
}

ini_set('display_errors','Off');
try {
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

and the part of main

```
 switch ($_GET['page']) {
case 'main':
    $page = getTemplate('main.tpl', array('user'=>$user));
    echo $page;
    break;
```

On VPS with freshly installed LAMP.

Comment: Test the rules 1 by 1 until you find what's causing the problem.

Comment: The RewriteRules didn't get better since your post yesterday. What does the error/access/RewriteLog say? Add a better description of what's happening / debugging steps taken so far.